# When I save as .SVG it adds extra whitespace width to the document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

I have my image on the artboard and have `clicked Object > Artboards > Fit to artboard bounds`.

[image]

When I save an SVG I get extra whitespace at the bottom, how can I just save whats in the artboard?  I have even selected just the 'artboard 1' in the save options, still whitespace.

Here is what am I talking about

[image]

Comment: What is the size of the artboard and image?

Comment: Crop the art to match the artboard rather than using clipping masks.

Comment: its 960 x 560px.

Comment: Then there must be *something* at the bottom of the image.

Comment: It would appear that the focal point for the "rays" is at the bottom edge... eluding to the use of a clipping mask.... http://i.stack.imgur.com/wnf2P.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Illustrator save dialog, there is an option where you can check 'Use Artboards'. Check this and it will save the image to the exact size of your artboard.

**EDIT** (from comment)

When using the `Save As...` dialog, it will save the artboard-cropped file as filename-01.svg. (note the -01 suffix). I assume you're checking that file, which means it is likely a bug in AI.

Try exporting as an `.eps` with artboard on, then export that to a `.svg`. Otherwise you may need to remove all vectors outside the artboard manually. Check for stray vectors, and if anything is hanging out over the edge of the artboard, try using the Pathfinder tool to manually crop to the artboard.

As a last resort, you can also edit the .SVG file in a code editor as it is XML based.

Comment: already tried this, still produces the above result

Comment: When using the save as dialog, it will save the artboard-cropped file as filename-01.svg. (note the -01 suffix). I assume you're checking that file, which means it is likely a bug in AI. Try exporting as an .EPS with artboard on, then export that to the .SVG. Otherwise you may need to remove all vectors outside the artboard manually. Check for stray vectors, and if anything is hanging out over the edge of the artboard, try using the Pathfinder tool to manually crop to the artboard. You can also access the .SVG file in a code editor as it is XML based, you might be able to fix it there.

Comment: Yes changing xml source fixed my issue, thankyou :)

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles I'm having the same issue as you when trying to export my SVGs. What exactly did you change about the XML that fixed your issue?

Comment: Wow! I don't understand what's going on, but if I even rename the file and take off -01 it reverts back to this weird state... Weird.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across a similar problem and found that if you untick **Responsive** in the **More options** panel in the svg export save as thing it stops the extra whitespace. Not sure what this is or why it is ticked by default. Using creative cloud, not sure if that option is in earlier versions

Comment: Hi alexrogins, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that svg files often carry with them hidden elements. I use the direct selection tool (A) to capture just what I need from the svg file and then copy that to a new file.

Comment: Tried this, selected the elements, created new document and pasted in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `.svg` as a copy, not go through the `File > Scripts > SaveDocsAsSVG` option. The `save as copy` gives you the option to save artboards or not. You can also check the `XML` code before saving too with this route.